# advice on rails 4 rendering of views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I looking for the correct way to do the following.

I have a controller action 'show' that really only gets a database entry like:

```
def show 
  @photo = Photo.find params[:photo_id]
end
```

I have four different views that all use the same controller action. How would I implement this?

I have thought of two ways:

1) use a url parameter:

```
def show 
  @photo = Photo.find params[:photo_id]

  case params[:view]
  when 'view1'
    render ...view1
  when 'view2'
    render ...view2
  when 'view3'
    render ...view3
  when 'view4'
    render ...view4

end
```

...or...

2) use respond_to

```
def show 
  @photo = Photo.find params[:photo_id]

  respond_to |view|
    view.one {render ...view1}
    view.two {render ...view2}
    view.three {render ...view3}
    view.four {render ...view4}

  end

end
```

...or... something totally different??

You tell me?

Comment: Define 'correct' — this seems quite opinionated

Comment: You could do your first option. However, if you have any differentiating factor other than passing view param, use it. For example, show different views based on wheather user is signed in, a photo has a certain attribute, iser is admin, etc etc. this way it would be easier to maintain.

Comment: @andrew-l - give me your opinion.

Comment: @PetrGazarov I have used the param form now - just seems a bit rough. The reason I have 4 views is that a photo and it's meta data can be shown in 4 different ways...so nothing fancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call the view the same as params[:view], like such:

```
def show 
  @photo = Photo.find params[:photo_id]
  render params[:view].to_sym
end
```

As long as you have view files that cover all possible parameters, that will work.